# solve system of two ODE of first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

I want to solve the following system of ODE
$$
\begin{cases}
y_1' = 3y_1 - y_2 +1\\
y_2'= 4 y_1 +2 y_2 +x\\[.5em]
y_1(0)= 1, y_2(0)= 0
\end{cases}
$$
For this, I calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, and I found  $\lambda_1= \dfrac{5-\sqrt{15}i}{2}$ and $\lambda_2= \dfrac{5+\sqrt{15}i}{2}$.

Now I search the eigenvectors associated to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Let $v_1$ the eigenvector associated to $\lambda_1$, then $(A-\lambda_1 Id) v_1=0$.

We put 
$v_1= (x,y)$ and we resolve the system
$$
\begin{cases}
(3-\lambda_1) x - y =0\\
4 x + (2-\lambda_1)y =0
\end{cases}
$$
My problem is that I obtain $x=y=0$, and it's not normally to found $v_1=0$.

How do we find the eigenvector associate to $\lambda_1$?

Comment: your first mistake is the eigenvalues, which should be$\frac{5 \pm i \sqrt{15}}{2}$

Comment: can you help me for eigenvector? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the first equation of the linear system for the first eigenvalue the eigenvector is (a multiple of) $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\3-λ_1}$. This inserted into the second equation $$4\cdot 1+(2-λ_1)\cdot(3-λ_1)=λ_1^2-5λ_1+10=0$$ just reproduces the characteristic equation. Thus if you insert the correct root into the linear system, you should get non-trivial solutions.

The linear system for the first eigenvector $v_1=\pmatrix{v_{11}\\v_{21}}$ is (after multiplying everything by $2$)
\begin{cases}
(1+\sqrt{15}i)v_{11}-2v_{21}=0\\
8v_{11}+(-1+\sqrt{15}i)v_{21}=0
\end{cases}
and indeed the second equation is a multiple by the factor of $\frac{1-\sqrt{15}i}2$ of the first equation.

---

Note that by the same reasoning, $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\3-λ_2}$ is one variant for the second eigenvector.

Comment: I don't uderstand. We use one equation to find $v_1$? Fot the first equation we have $v_1=(1,3-\lambda_1)$ and for the second equation we have $v_2=(1, \dfrac{2-\lambda_1}{4})$. How we make choose between twice? Please

Comment: $λ_1$ being an eigenvalue means that $A-λ_1I$ does not have full rank means that the two equations of the eigen value system are linearly dependent. Any solution of the first equation is also a solution of the second equation. And yes, that means that the vectors $\pmatrix{1\\3-λ_1}$ and $\pmatrix{λ_1-2\\4}$ are multiples of each other.

Comment: so we can choose $(1,3-\lambda_1)$ or $(\lambda_1-2,4)$, it is the same?

Comment: Qualitatively the same, as they span the same eigenspace, quantitatively they are different vectors, the second is the $λ_1−2$ fold multiple of the first.